# Performance for Aurora views vs. MySql views

Tags: mysql, performance, view, amazon-aurora

I've found MySql views to be one of the most common performance pitfalls, mostly for reasons mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545866/471321).

> The biggest drawback is in how MySQL processes a view, whether it's
>   stored or inline. MySQL will always run the view query and materialize
>   the results from that query as a temporary MyISAM
>
> One big drawback of a view is that predicates from the outer query
>   NEVER get pushed down into the view

What are the performance differences (if any) for views in Aurora compared to MySql?

Do Aurora views necessarily materialize without considering predicates on the outer query?

Comment: I don't think Aurora will bring anything new for that. Actually I am thinking completely opposite. For general Aurora will be slower than MySql for everything because it doesn't support table compression. And right now we are experiencing that problem.

Comment: As I see it, Amazon RDS Aurora is hardware and scripts built around a minimally-modified MySQL.  I seriously doubt if anything is changed in VIEWs, optimization, etc.  The online explanation of "5x" is vague enough to fall into "it's easy to make any point you like with a carefully crafted benchmark".